# How to override (or a least view) the RDNSS ipv6 DNS? (root)

Tags: root-access, dns, firewall, ipv6, iptables

As far as ipv4 DNS is concerned, Android (at least version 9) can override default DNS settings fairly well.

Firstly, it is possible to set net.dns* to the desired value.

Secondly, `iptables -t nat` works, and lets the user redirect the packets to port 53 anywhere required.

With ipv6 however, things are not that easy. Android 9 (at least mine) does not support  `ip6tables -t nat`. Moreover, Android sets some internal DNS-related setting when obtaining the DNS address from SLAAC/RDNSS, which is not reflected in `getprop`, and insists on using it, regardless of what is in net.dns*.

The only tool I am aware of, that might be somehow useful, is `ip6tables -t mangle`, but it still seems quite limited.

How can I override (or at least view) the default DNS address obtained from RDNSS?

Comment: Try `dumpsys connectivity | grep CONNECTED | grep -i dns`

Comment: try disabling ipv6 and try. Thats how I got to use nat table on ipv6 traffic. I have never seen and android version with ipv6 nat.